Finding Dynamic Groups in Azure AD based on Specific Rules Syntax within Powershell
I have tried to find all the Dynamic groups within my Azure AD Environment via Powershell using the below Command:
Get-AzureADMSGroup | Where-Object { $_.MembershipRule -like '*user.country -eq "Singapore"*' } | Select-Object DisplayName, MembershipRule | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\Groups.txt"; notepad.exe "C:\Temp\Groups.txt"

The output file is empty even though I am certain that a bunch of groups have this specific Rules Syntax.
I'm not entirely sure where to start with debugging this.
I've tried a conversation with ChatGPT about it which gave me this line to check all dynamic groups but this came up blank in the output file too:
Get-AzureADMSGroup | Where-Object { $_.MembershipRule -ne $null } | Select-Object DisplayName, MembershipRule | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\AllGroups.txt"; notepad.exe "C:\Temp\AllGroups.txt"

There were various other lines that refer to case sensitive searches and searching based on a pattern but they all came up blank too.
I know my search criteria is correct as I copied it direct from one group that had this rule.
Is there anything else I am missing here?

Is this solution works for you?

I tried to reproduce same in my enviornment, I created multiple dynamic groups with Membership Rule (user.country -eq "Singapore")  and with other Membership rule.

Ensure that the syntax of the MembershipRule is configured correctly

Use below modified powershell command:
 Get-AzureADMSGroup | Where-Object { $_.MembershipRule -match 'user\.country\s+-eq\s+"Singapore"' } | Select-Object DisplayName, MembershipRule  | Out-File -FilePath "<filepath>"; notepad.exe "<filepath>"
Response:

